# Javascript/jQuery won't hide HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to hide a section in my HTML code, but I already tried everything, I even used jQuery, but it just doesn't work, it won't hide it either way.

```
<div class="coding2">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="JavS">
                <h1>JavaScript</h1>
                <span class="barr"></span>
                <p>bla bla bla bla bla</p>
            </div>
            <div class="htmlCSS">
                <h1>HTML/CSS</h1>
                <span class="barr"></span>
                <p>bla bla bla bla bla </p>
            </div>
            <div class="php">
                <h1>PHP</h1>
                <span class="barr"></span>
                <p>bla bla bla bla bla</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the top of the HTML file, and I don't think the problem is here.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main-jquery.js"></script>
</head>
```

I already tried everything like I said, usually I google the hell out of it before trying to ask it somewhere, but this time, I can't figure out why it isn't hiding.

@edit

The code I tried in "main-jquery.js"

(with jQuery)

```
$(function(){
    $('.coding2').hide();
});
```

(with pure JavaScript)

```
document.getElementById(".coding2").style.visibility = "none";
```

and

```
document.getElementById("#coding2").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

(yes, when did the last one I edited the class "coding2" to id="coding2" but it didn't do anything)

I want to hide the entire div "coding2"

@edit2

I got what I wanted, special thanks to: @Fabio and @JamesBurton
(thanks everyone!)

Comment: You need to add the code you've tried. Perhaps you're not waiting for the DOM to load but we can't tell.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit with it

Comment: what `getElementById(".coding2")` ? you shouldn't use `.` or `#` when you use javascript

Comment: Have you tried just putting `.coding2 {display:none}` in your CSS instead of using JavaScript to do CSS's job?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Oh god, I completely forgot to do this. Thank you so much!!!!!! But I want to know if it can be done with JS, which I think will give me better results in the future.

Comment: @FastSnail Yeah, I already did it without the "." and "#" but it didn't worked aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see you haven't actually called the function that hides it. You need to decide whether you want it to be hidden on button click etc. (so add a button that calls the function).

If you want it to be hidden by default then add in your JavaScript document below the div you want to hide and add this to before your function `window.onload = function(){ //enter your code };` This is for pure JavaScript by the way.

You also need to add an ID to your divs because what you have now is a class so add `id="coding2"` and you don't need the # or . in your getElementByID.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Given what you've told me in the comments of this answer I would say that you should look into creating a grid system with CSS. Here is a very good tutorial on making one http://j4n.co/blog/Creating-your-own-css-grid-system

Then you can use %s to make sure your layout adapt and change the sizes based on screen size doing media calls. I don't think JS is the way to go.

I saw in the comments of the main question that using `display: none` in CSS did what you want. In order to do that with JS just add that CSS style with JS by doing `document.getElementById("coding2").style.display = "none";`.

Comment: Ah yeah, I wanted it in pure JS. Now it worked, but it seems that the element still there but it's invisble, I want it to complete hide itself, like the .hide() in jQuery does. 

I'm using = 'none' but it isn't working at all.

Comment: @gfpdv What are you trying to do because at the moment you're making something that doesn't exist so what is the point in the HTML you're making? What is it that needs to be completely hidden?

Comment: I'm trying to do a resizable website, so if someone opens in a mobile, the website change the layout using media queries, but, if the screen is for example larger than "width = 800px" I want to hide the layout for mobile, and use the standard layout.

Comment: @gfpdv I updated my answer to help you a bit more, I don't think you should be using JavaScript for that, look into liquid layouts and grids.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much, and sorry for misunderstanding, I think I wasn't clear enough in my initial post. :(

Comment: @gfpdv No problem, I also just added a bit at the end of my answer to show how to do `display: none` with JS because I noticed in the main comments that you wanted to do that. If you're question is answered now please mark my answer as a solution :)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you are wrapping the hide function in $(document).ready()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.coding2').hide();
});
```

This will hide the element on page load.

Or with pure javascript:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    Your HTML here

    <script>
        document.querySelector('.coding2').style.display = 'none';
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Or with CSS:

```
.coding2 {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: But how can I do it without jQuery?

Comment: No, I mean, it's working perfectly, but it doesn't execute what I wanted to do. haha

Comment: The question was, what do you want it to do?

Answer (score 0):

add an id to your div and use code below

```
<div id="coding2" class="coding2">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="JavS">
                <h1>JavaScript</h1>
                <span class="barr"></span>
                <p>bla bla bla bla bla</p>
            </div>
            <div class="htmlCSS">
                <h1>HTML/CSS</h1>
                <span class="barr"></span>
                <p>bla bla bla bla bla </p>
            </div>
            <div class="php">
                <h1>PHP</h1>
                <span class="barr"></span>
                <p>bla bla bla bla bla</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>

  $(function(){
    $('#coding2').hide();
});

</script>
```

Comment: You're not using a <script> tag to wrap your jQuery